# Using Graphics to plot data

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to plot a 2D data as points using `Graphics` function. I would like to plot the points as six or five-pointed star; how to do that using `Graphics`? Also I would like to plot these points using a plotrange kind of thing, e.g. I have a dataset where x-column values range from 0.8 to 4.5 and y-values range from 0 to 4.5; I would like to plot the data using a plotrange: {{0.8,2.1},{0,2.0}} and I am using `Graphics[Points[Most#@]]&/@data`, when I am doing this all data points are being plotted beyond the plotrange I want them to be plotted for. How do I use a `PlotRange` like function to use in graphics. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Comment: What do you mean by `x=(0,100)`? Are you looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njvHd.png)? over some range? Please load your data.

Comment: `ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Style[\[FivePointedStar], 14]]` or with `Style[\[SixPointedStar], 14]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`PolygonMarker`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker):

```
datasets = RandomReal[{0 , 2.5}, {4, 20, 2}];

Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1], JoinForm["Miter"]}],
  EdgeForm[Blue], 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["SixPointedStarSlim", Offset[7], datasets[[1]]],
  EdgeForm[Red], 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["FivePointedStarThick", Offset[7], datasets[[2]]],
  EdgeForm[Darker@Green], 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["SixPointedStar", Offset[7], datasets[[3]]],
  EdgeForm[Darker@Yellow], 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["FivePointedStar", Offset[7], datasets[[4]]]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 550, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.8, 2.1}, {0, 2.0}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: Thanks Alexey, this is working well

Comment: @mjm You are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
dat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
t1 = 0.02 Table[{Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {p, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/5}];
t2 = 0.005 Table[{Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {p, 2 Pi/10, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/5}];
star[r_] := Line[(r + #) & /@ Riffle[t1, t2]]
Graphics[star /@ dat]
```

[image]